# How to sum up the duplicated value and keep all the rows on R

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a dataset like this

```
V0  V1  V2 
1   A   21 
2   A   21  
3   B   22  
4   C   23  
5   C   23
```

So there are duplicated value in V1; and I would like to create a dataset like this, which sum up V2 but keeping the duplicates in V1:

```
V0  V1  V2 
1   A   42 
2   A   42  
3   B   22  
4   C   46  
5   C   46
```

thanks

Answer (score 3):

We can use `ave` from `base R`

```
df1$V2 <- with(df1, ave(V2, V1, FUN = sum))
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(V1) %>%
   mutate(V2 = sum(V2))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can also use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)[,V2:=sum(V2),by=V1]
```